# How to do while loop with if exist in SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm just learning to use while loop in stored procedure I'm not sure why the stored procedure does not return any value.

I'm using the if exist to check whether the id exist in the table or not.
And if there is more than 1 id I need to execute again the same query.

I tried using while loop and its not working.

I declare the `@keyValue` as `Varchar` and it causes an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'c29dc109b310479fa5c281eb20c61656' to data type int.

That is why I use `COUNT` at the `WHILE`

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT t1.ref_id 
           FROM pbosproinvoiceitem t1 
           WHERE t1.ref_id = @keyValue)
    WHILE COUNT(@keyValue) > 1
    BEGIN
        --need to do for loop
        SELECT @balWghtSso = (SELECT t1.act_wght  
                              FROM ccossoitem t1 
                              WHERE t1.master_id = @keyValue) - 
                             (SELECT t1.wght 
                              FROM ccossoitem t1 
                              WHERE t1.master_id = @keyValue)
        SELECT @balWghtBl = (SELECT t1.act_wght 
                             FROM ccosblitem t1 
                             WHERE t1.master_id = @keyValue) - 
                            (SELECT t1.wght 
                             FROM ccosblitem t1 
                             WHERE t1.master_id = @keyValue)

        SELECT DISTINCT 
            t1.debtor_code AS customer_code, t1.tml_code, t1.scn, 
            t2.cg_type, t3.qty, @balWghtSso AS mea, t3.vol,
            CASE 
               WHEN t3.from_loc = 'DL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
            END AS ex_wharf,
            t2.dg_flg, 0 AS conveyor_ind, t1.sso_num AS ref_doc_num,
            t1.id AS ref_id
        FROM 
            ccosso t1
        INNER JOIN 
            ccossoitem t2 ON t1.id = t2.master_id
        INNER JOIN 
            ccosgodown t3 ON t3.blso_id = t1.id AND t3.blso_item_id = t2.id
        WHERE 
            t3.move_type = 'LOAD'
            AND t1.id = @keyValue

        UNION ALL

        SELECT DISTINCT 
            t1.debtor_code AS customer_code, t1.tml_code, t1.scn, 
            t2.cg_type, t3.qty, 
            @balWghtBl AS mea, t3.vol, 
            CASE 
               WHEN t3.from_loc = 'DD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
            END AS ex_wharf,
            t2.dg_flg, 0 AS conveyor_ind, t1.bl_num AS ref_doc_num,
            t1.id AS ref_id
        FROM 
            ccosbl t1
        INNER JOIN 
            ccosblitem t2 ON t1.id = t2.master_id
        INNER JOIN 
            ccosgodown t3 ON t3.blso_id = t1.id AND t3.blso_item_id = t2.id
        WHERE 
            t3.move_type = 'DELV'
            AND t1.id = @keyValue
    END;
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: i'm using the sql server 2008

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-write your while loop like below, and remove the IF exists condition.

```
WHILE( SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM pbosproinvoiceitem t1 
WHERE t1.ref_id = @keyValue > 1)
```